# Server 2008 print server down / access denied

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, networking, active-directory

I have two Server 2008 servers (both running as VMs in VMware). One is a Full Installation, and the other is a Server Core installation. I just installed Print Services on both of them. In Print Management on the Full server, I added the Server Core print server (so now two print servers are listed in Print Management). However, the icon for my Server Core print server has a red, down-pointing arrow (indicating that it is down, I suppose). And when I right-click it and click Add Printer, I get a message saying that access is denied.

Can someone tell me how to bring up or check on the status of the Server Core print server. Obviously, I'm somewhat of a noob with this stuff. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

2008 has firewall active by default, with inbound filtering. As a quick test, disable the firewall on the Core:

> netsh advfirewall set currentprofile state off

It should now be working. Then you can activate again the firewall and allow the blocked traffic (RPC i guess).

2 ways:

- Locally on the core, through command line
- With the firewall MMC from the other server

First way:

> netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Rules to enable" new enable=yes

Second way:
On the core, allow remote management:

> netsh advfirewall set currentprofile settings remotemanagement enable

Then, on the non core server, you must launch mmc, add the **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security** console, so you are prompt to specify a remote computer

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Remote Server Management Service also.
I've bunch of 2008 Servers that I manage throught my office laptop with this MMC Service, but to use it you've to activate it on the server first.